# Big Theta Notation

Tags: algorithms, asymptotics

> 1. Does every algorithm for performing multiplication of binary
>      strings of length $n$ has a runtime complexity that is $\Theta(n^2)$?
> 2. Give an example of a function that is $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$ but not $\Theta(n^3)$

Given functions $f$ and $g$, if both $f = \mathcal{O}(g)$ and $g = \mathcal{O}(f)$ then we write $f = \Theta(g)$.

1. I want to say no since for example Karatsuba multiplication is $\mathcal{O}(n^{log_2(3)})$
2. I don't know about number 2.

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: 1. Correct. Or you easily can make multiplication algorithms that are _too slow_ to run in $\Theta(n^2)$, just by including enough irrelevant busywork. 2. How about $n^2$?

Comment: Wait $n^2$ is $\mathcal{O}(n^3)$?

Comment: x @Cool: Sure, why wouldn't it be? For every $n>1$ it holds that $n^2\le 1\cdot n^3$.

Comment: Oh right . Thanks.